# JSON not fired the event on MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to do cascading on the 2 dropdown with JSON, after I applied the code, the JSON should query my data on subcategory dropdown after I select on the Category dropdown. But nothing happen.

Did I do something wrong in my code?

**Controller :**

```
public ActionResult Create()
{     
   ViewBag.Category = ads.Categories.ToList();

   ViewBag.SubCategory = ads.SubCategories.ToList();    

   return View();
}
private IList<SubCategory> GetSubCategory(int id_category)
{            
   return ads.SubCategories.Where(m => m.id_category == id_category).ToList();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult LoadSubcategoryByCategory(string id_category)
{
   var SubCategoryList = this.GetSubCategory(Convert.ToInt32(id_category));

   var SubCategoryData = SubCategoryList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
       {
           Text = m.name.ToString(),
           Value = m.id.ToString()
       });
   return Json(SubCategoryData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlCategory").change(function () {
            var category_id = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("../Ads/LoadSubcategoryByCategory", { id_category: category_id },
                    function (SubCategoryData) {
                        var select = $("#ddlSubCategory");
                        select.empty();
                        select.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: 0,
                            text: "-Select a SubCategory-"
                        }));

                        $.each(SubCategoryData, function (index, itemData) {
                              alert(SubCategoryData);
                            select.append($('<option/>', {
                                value: itemData.Value,
                                text: itemData.Text
                            }));
                        });
                    });
         });
</script>

        <div class="editor-label">
            Category :
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down"> 
         @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.id_category, new SelectList(ViewBag.Category as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "id", "name"),
            "-Choose Category-", new { id = "ddlCategory" })     
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Subcategory :  
        </div>
        <div class="drop-down"> 
            @Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.id_subcategory, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "id", "name"),
         "-Choose SubCategory-", new { id = "ddlSubCategory" })   
        </div>
```

Hopefully someone can help me.

---

**UPDATE**

In my console firefox shows

`[10:24:59.464] ReferenceError: $ is not defined @ http://localhost:63280/Ads/Create:29`

`[10:25:03.565] Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. @ http://localhost:63280/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js:3446`

`[10:25:08.284] Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true. @ http://localhost:63280/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js:2378`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now is works, I just move the code to the under

> @section Scripts{  }

then  I add the

> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

Please see the example on the below.

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {          

            $('#cat').change(function () {
                var category_id = $('#cat').val();
                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("LoadSub", "Ads")',
            {
                id_category: category_id
            },

          function (SubCategoryData) {
              var select = $("#subCat");
              select.empty();
              select.append($('<option/>',
              {
                  value: 0,
                  text: "-Select a SubCategory-"
              }));

              $.each(SubCategoryData, function (index, itemData) {

                  select.append($('<option/>',
                  {
                      value: itemData.Value,
                      text: itemData.Text
                  }));
              });
          });
            });
        });
</script>    
}
```

Note : I already change the dropdown id from **ddlCategory** to **cat** and **ddlSubCategory** to **subCat**

Answer (score 0):

Before you use any debug do not use a relative URL like `../Ads/LoadSubcategoryByCategory` with any event.

It is better to use `@Url.Action("someaction", "somecontroller")`:

```
 $.getJSON("@Url.Action("LoadSubcategoryByCategory", "Ads")",
```

Comment: Already change to `$.getJSON('@Url.Action("LoadSubcategoryByCategory", "Ads")', { id_category: category_id }` . Still nothing changes.

Comment: do you know how to use console in firefox

Comment: Not to much, let me check and comment if I got something.

Comment: make sure your js is valid your script

Comment: How can I check my JS is valid?

Comment: @Already check, My JS is valid and no have any problem. But still cannot fired the event

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
$.getJSON("./LoadSubcategoryByCategory", .....
```

Comment: Same also, nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
  select.appedn($("<option></option>").attr("value", itemData.Value).text(itemData.Text))
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Already tried.. Still same.. I just weird why my json not trigger the function from controller?